# How to move keyframes using Python?

Tags: python, keyframes

Is there a way to move a keyframe using Python (change the frame at which the keyframe is set)?

The keyframe already exists. I need to access it and move it, with the script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not hard:

```
bpy.data.actions[aname].fcurves[i].keyframe_points[j].co[0] = fr1
```

The tricky part is picking the right `fcurve[i]` and `keyframe_points[j]` if there are more than one.  You'll have to check `fcurve[i].data_path` and (if it's a vector data_path like location or rotation*) `fcurve[i].array_index` to make sure you're altering the right fcurve.

Comment: You can also access `co[0]` and `co[1]` like `co.x` (frame) and `co.y` (value). The action associated with an object is accessible via `Object.animation_data.action`. Note that both `animation_data` and `action` can be `None`.